# How to override afterRequest inside a Store

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Based on this fix: http://bit.ly/1Pf59ui, you have to extend "Ext.data.proxy.Ajax". However, one of my stores look like this:

```
Ext.define('EcommBackoffice.store.Banks',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'EcommBackoffice.model.BankModel',
    storeId: 'bank-store-id',
    autoLoad:false,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'name',
        direction:'ASC'
    }],
    config: {
        loaded:false
    },
    isLoaded: function(){
        return this.getLoaded()
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(currentthis, records, successful){
            if(successful === true){
                this.setLoaded(true)    
            }
        }
    },
    proxy: {
        $configStrict: false,
        type: 'rest',
        id: 'app-banks',
        url: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'bank'
        },
        api:{
            create: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks,
            update: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks,
            destroy: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks
        },

        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, op) {
                var oBankStore = Ext.getStore('bank-store-id');
                if(response.status === 403 || response.status === 401 || response.status === 503) return; /*skip this exception handler and refer to Applciation Controller handler*/
                Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR', response.responseText + ' ' +response.statusText);
            }            
        },
        afterRequest:function(request,success){
            if(request.method = 'POST' && success){
                var oAddBankWindow = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#add-bank-window');
                if(oAddBankWindow[0]) {
                    oAddBankWindow[0].down('#msgPanel').update('<span style="">New bank added</span>');
                    oAddBankWindow[0].down('#countryName').update('');
                    oAddBankWindow[0].down('form').getForm().reset();
                }
            }
        }              
    }


});
```

How can I extend "Ext.data.proxy.Ajax" if I am already extending "Ext.data.Store?" When i use `$configStrict` to allow the override, the current error gets replaced with this one:

`Uncaught TypeError: sorter.getRoot is not a function`

What should be the proper way of fixing this? I am currently upgrading an existing ExtJS 4.2 application to 6.x.

Comment: You'll might want to look for a better solution that does not result in a mix of data and view..

Comment: Why dont you use store events/listeners instead of afterRequest method ?

Answer (score 2):

Ext.data.Store and Ext.data.proxy.Ajax are two different class not for the same purpose. Store is **using** the proxy.

So the way I'll do it in ExtJs 6 is to create a custom proxy, extending the REST proxy (in your case), and set the *type* to your custom proxy.

```
/**
 * Custom Proxy
 **/
Ext.define('EcommBackoffice.proxy.MyRestProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
    alias: 'proxy.bank-proxy',

    /**
     * @override
     **/
    afterRequest:function(request,success){

        this.callParent(arguments); // call to parent as this is a template method

        if(request.method = 'POST' && success){
            var oAddBankWindow = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#add-bank-window');
            if(oAddBankWindow[0]) {
                oAddBankWindow[0].down('#msgPanel').update('<span style="">New bank added</span>');
                oAddBankWindow[0].down('#countryName').update('');
                oAddBankWindow[0].down('form').getForm().reset();
            }
        }
    }

});

Ext.define('EcommBackoffice.store.Banks',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['EcommBackoffice.proxy.MyRestProxy'],

    model:'EcommBackoffice.model.BankModel',
    storeId: 'bank-store-id',
    autoLoad:false,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'name',
        direction:'ASC'
    }],
    // Already existing in Extjs 6
    // config: {
    //     loaded:false
    // },
    // isLoaded: function(){
    //     return this.getLoaded()
    // },
    // listeners: {
    //     load: function(currentthis, records, successful){
    //         if(successful === true){
    //             this.setLoaded(true)    
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    proxy: {
        type: 'bank-proxy',
        id: 'app-banks',
        url: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'bank'
        },
        api:{
            create: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks,
            update: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks,
            destroy: EcommBackoffice.Global.getAPIEndPoints().banks
        },

        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, op) {
                var oBankStore = Ext.getStore('bank-store-id');
                if(response.status === 403 || response.status === 401 || response.status === 503) return; /*skip this exception handler and refer to Applciation Controller handler*/
                Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR', response.responseText + ' ' +response.statusText);
            }            
        }         
    }

});
```

Comment: I followed this and I still get the `Uncaught TypeError: sorter.getRoot is not a function` error.

Comment: I've add a little edit (commenting the config loaded), try with this one please. Your sorter config seems good. I suppose this error come from an others part of your code...

Comment: Still getting the same error `Uncaught TypeError: sorter.getRoot is not a function`. Also, I applied this to the rest of my stores. Is getting this warning normal?  `[Ext.define] Duplicate class name 'EcommBackoffice.proxy.RestProxy' specified, must be a non-empty string` Or is there a better way of applying this to all the stores that needed that proxy?

Comment: You are transitioning from Ext 4 to Ext 6 if I understand well. If not already done, I suggest to read : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/data_package.html. According the doc, they suggest to attached the proxy to the Model not the Store (at least for the default behavior). And so the method to do that is to create a schema. For example, in my app, I have _MyApp.model.Base_ which define a schema with a proxy type: 'myproxy'. All my model are extending _MyApp.model.Base_, so my proxy is used all over my app. Hope it can help! Transition is not easy.

Comment: For the sorter error, it seems to me that it's a different problem. Remove the sorter of the sorter to see if it's coming from that. Then check around your data... you have _rootProperty_ so this assume that your date are like { "bank": [// jsondata here]}. If not, then you have your error...